# How can we initialise a state in react typescript in constructor method, If it has a specific interface type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have the below Code: Where I have an interface type for a state. How do i initialize it in constructor method. As It doesn't allow me to initialize to string/ null/ number

> `interface IState { selectedUser?: IUserMenu}`
>
> `class AssignUser extends React.Component<IProps, IState>{
>       constructor(props: IProps) {
>           super(props); 
>           this.state = {
>           selectedUser: ' what i have to put here' }}}`

Also what does it mean by 
`this.state ={}`
 in the constructor function means ?

IUserMenu is an interface, so I cannot initialize to number, '', null,

Only thing I can use Is `undefined`

Comment: The `this.state = {}` call in the constructor sets the initial state for the component. Perhaps just pass `this.state = {}` if you don't have an initial value for `state.selectedUser` -- your interface indicates it is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @ankitjayaprakash ,

I've an example with your case where I'm initializing the object you want to pass described in the interface (but without being optional)

You can see it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-5wbink)

What "this.state={}" serves in the constructor is only to initialize the state of that component, even though it could be out without any builder function.

Comment: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'IUserMenu | undefined'.

Am getting this error

Comment: It works for me without any error on the part of Typescript but if you want better open a CodeSandbox or a StackBlitz and copy all the code. This way we can help you better.

Comment: Thanks @fg93 for you effort, I works but I get TSLint suggestion. Thats fine. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your IState interface specifies that it has one property called `selectedUser` that is optional (as it has a ? after it).

If you *do* provide a `selectedUser`, it must of type `IUserMenu`. So your `what i have to put here` is an object that conforms to the `IUserMenu` interface.

this.state = {}  means initialise the state with the object defined in the braces. In your case the object defined in the braces must match your IState interface (so contain a single property called `selectedUser` that is `undefined` of type `IUserMenu`)

Comment: Iam using selectedUser state in the Picker props `selectedUser`
But I need to initialize this state in the constructor

But my <item> value is an object
In this case what should i have initialized to ?

Comment: What does the IUserMenu interface look like? And is one of these types passed in as a prop?

Comment: `interface IUserMenu {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
}`

Comment: Ok, well it doesn't seem to make sense to me to initialise it to anything...  you could just do: `this.state = { selectedUser: undefined }` or not bother setting the state at all in the constructor

Comment: Or, you could even intialise it like this: `this.state = {selectedUser: { name: "", surname: "" }}`